# creating a camera view with button for android

Tags: android, android-camera

i have set up an activity that loads up the camera and allows me to preview it but i need to add a button to the screen but the only way i can get the screen to display is by using the following layout:

```
<android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.view.SurfaceView>
```

is there a way for me to add a button to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `SurfaceView` and button into a `RelativeLayout`.  Both of those types of layouts allow views to overlap so your button will be on top of your `SurfaceView`.  The set up would be something like this

```
<RelativeLayout>  
    <SurfaceView></SurfaceView>  
    <Button></Button>  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried this layout before i settled on the current one and the relative layout wouldnt work

Answer (score -1):

DeeV's answer is correct for the RelativeLayout part. The FrameLayout isn't intented to contain multiple children. So the RelativeLayout is the way to go.

Comment: You are right about that.  I edited my answer.  However, I do think it's possible though it's not "intended."